# typo3 indexed search duplicate news entries

Tags: search, typo3, tt-news

I found a problem with indexed search. I have news entries with different categories. Each newsentry can have several categories. When I am searching the newsentry is found several times, because it is found in several categories. I could not find a workaround that indexed search only displays one entry if it is in several categories.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a content element containing the plugin for the news list you can access several configuration options. One is called "Exclude already displayed news" (on 'Additional'-Tab). Did you try this?

Comment: do you mean tt_news with news?  I do not find "Exclude already displayed news" using typo3 v6.2 and tt_news 3.6.0

Comment: No, I described the extension "news", not "tt_news". tt_news is not up to date anymore and should be migrated to news. More details for migration can be found [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/3.0.0/Main/Tutorial/MigrationFromTtNews/Index.html).

Comment: Anyway for tt_news you can find some hints for correct indexed search configuration [here](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html#c882).